# Sharepoint extremely slow. Where to begin

Tags: performance, sharepoint, intranet

Our company's Sharepoint server has a list of different projects with associated files for each one of them.

Whenever I (or any of the people in the company) navigate the site (which is in our intranet) it feels responsive and everything loads just fine.

The problem is when we go to one of the file lists in one of the projects and select "Open in Windows Explorer". The windows explorer window opens, but it takes forever, at least one minute to open the window, and every time you enter a folder it takes around 30 seconds to open the folder, and copying files is also extremely slow (Around 10KB/s).

The rest of the things in the network seem to be fine, we can copy files from a computer's share to another very fast, as well as download things from Internet just as fast (we have like a 40Mb connection).

If I ping the address of the Sharepoint server (ping intranet.mycompany.net) it replies from a 192.168.0. computer, which means it is resolving it correctly as an internal address, and it has a response time of 1ms, which surely is good.

My question is, how can I start trying to figure out what is going on? I have no clues and it's frustrating.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, go to Internet Options - Connections - LAN Settings.  Uncheck `Automatically detect settings`.